# Is there a way to switch the position of "high" to the right and and "low" to the left on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I just made an interaction analysis via two way ANOVA and created my graphic. Unfortunately on the x axis the condition high is alway on the left side, and the condition low is on the right side. But I want the condition "low" on the left side and "high" on the right side of the x axis.

I already tried to import my data the other way round so, that condition low x low is on top of my list and at the and of the list there ist the data with condition high x high.

```
ggline(dataH3, x= "news_source", y="sharing_intention", color = "rec_source", 
       add = c("mean_se"), palette = c("blue", "red"), shape=1, 
       title = "The Effect of News Source Credibility on Sharing Intention", xlab = "News Source Recommendation", 
       ylab = "Sharing Intention", legend.title = "Recommendation source credibility", ggtheme = theme_bw()) + 
       theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

There was no error message, but still I would like to change the layout.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dataH3)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dataH3, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply relevel your factor variable (high and low are factor levels and R oders them alphabetically):

```
dataH3$news_source <- factor(dataH3$news_source, levels = c("low", "high"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!